# CSS for Bullet Points in Recent Posts

Tags: r, html-lists, styling

I am trying to style the bullet points in the recent post widget in the footer area of the website.  The theme I am using has color settings and when I change the color it impacts the site globally; however, I just need the changes in that particular section of the site (footer > Recent Posts).

I used the developer tools to pinpoint the css and found

```
.widget_product_categories ul li, .widget_nav_menu ul li, .widget_archive ul li, .widget_pages ul li, .widget_categories ul li, .widget_recent_entries ul li, .widget_meta ul li, .widget_recent_comments ul li, #main_content ul.wp-block-archives li, #main_content ul.wp-block-categories li, #main_content ul.wp-block-latest-posts li
```

I believe this is the area that should impact changes

```
.widget_recent_entries ul li:
```

But when I try to add any styles to this (even using the !important; tag, I get no results) but nothing changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you want to see the site live [here is the link](https://dannaforsheriff.com)

Comment: Think I have it solved added .widget_recent_entries ul li:before, .widget_meta ul li:before {
background: #ffea00;
}